# Searching through an array for a name with a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, find

I need help in designing a for loop that returns the name if found and if it is not found it returns the requested name as not found. I need to do this without repeating the not found loop multiple times.

I have tried various if, else if, and else statements. I have also tried a do while loop inside of the for loop and also tried to do the not found statement outside of the loop

```
    String[] values = new String[12];
    int name = 1;

    // Initialize Scanner
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    // Create loop for name input 
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter in " + " the name of friend " + name++ + ": ");
        values[i] = new String(input.next());
        if (values[i].equalsIgnoreCase("zzzz")) 
    {
        break;
    }
    }

    // Create loop for name output
    System.out.println("\n" + "The names of your friends are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
    {
        if (values[i].equalsIgnoreCase("zzzz")) 
    {
        break;

    }
        else 
    {
        System.out.println(values[i]);
    }
    }

    // Search for the name
    boolean found = false;
    System.out.print("\n" + "Enter in the name of the friend you would like to find: ");
    String find = input.next();
    for(int i = 0;i < values.length && !found;++i) 
    {
        if (find.equalsIgnoreCase(values[i]))
        {
        System.out.println("\n" + "Your friend " + find + " was found");
        found = true;
        break;
        }
        else if (find != values[i] && (found = false))
        { 
        System.out.println("\n" + "Your friend " + find + " was not found" );
        break;
        }
    } 

    }
}
```

I expect the not found statement to not be reiterated multiple times through the loop until the actual name is found. If the name does not exist in the array, it should search through the whole array and return that it was not found.

Comment: Why did you put the your friend was not found statement in the loop then? If you move it after the loop and simply check found == false you will know after the entire array

Comment: I did as you instructed and put it outside the loop like so - and it worked perfectly!  if (find.equalsIgnoreCase(values[i]))
   {
   System.out.println("\n" + "Your friend " + find + " was found");
   found = true;
   break;
   }

  }
  if (found == false)
  { 
  System.out.println("\n" + "Your friend " + find + " was not found" );
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my attempt. I have cast all elements to lower case whilst we iterate through the array to ensure we don't miss a match. For example if we searched for 
"tom" and in the array we had "Tom" the match would be missed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {


    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean foundFlag = false;
        String[] values = new String[12];

        //Populate array
        for(int i = 0, x = 1; i < values.length; i ++, x ++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter name of friend " + x + ": " );
            String name = input.next();
            values[i] = name;
        }

        //Output all elements of the array
        System.out.println("\n" + "The names of your friends are: ");
        for(String x : values)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
        }

        //Find a friend
        System.out.print("\n" + "Enter in the name of the friend you would like to find: ");
        String find = input.next();


        //Iterate through array and check if Friend inside.
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i ++)
        {
            if(values[i].toLowerCase().equals(find.toLowerCase()))
            {
                foundFlag = true;
                break;
            }

        }

        //If friend in the array flag will be True, else flag will remain false.
        if (foundFlag)
        {
            System.out.println("Friend " + find + " found");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Friend " + find + " not found");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just create a function to do your searching:

```
public boolean findName(String[] items, String name) {
  if (items == null || items.length == 0 || name == null || name.trim().isEmpty()) return false;
  for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name.trim())) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Then where ever you need to find a friend:

```
boolean exists = findName(values, "Foo Bar");
if (exists) {
  System.out.println("Friend exists");
} else {
  System.out.println("Friend does not exists");
}
```

Comment: That seems to be a much cleaner and more efficient way than I was doing! I will integrate this into the program. I greatly appreciate your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also java 8 streams :

```
boolean found = Stream.of(values)
    .anyMatch(value -> value.equalsIgnoreCase(name));
```

Comment: That is a great way to search also, but it has not been discussed in my class so I would be unable to use it. Thanks for the recommendation though! I will definitely research that method more thoroughly!

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code :

```
    // Search for the name
        boolean found = false;
        System.out.print("\n" + "Enter in the name of the friend you would like to find: ");
        String find = input.next();
        for(int i = 0;i < values.length && !found;++i) 
        {
            if (find.toLowerCase().equals(values[i].toLowerCase()))
            {
            System.out.println("\n" + "Your friend " + find + " was found");
            found = true;
            break;
            }

        } 
if(!found){

            System.out.println("\n" + "Your friend " + find + " was not found" );


}

        }
```

Comment: That is the way I opted to do the code! Except I did it this way instead if (found == false)
  { 
  System.out.println("\n" + "Your friend " + find + " was not found" );
  }

Comment: Your way looks slightly cleaner though for sure.